# How to extract the fontname from \the\font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, strings, xstring

I know LaTeX doesn't have strings as such but I want to be able to get and save the human readable version of the current font name.

`\f@family` does not work as expected because it shows the base font not the variant.

I saw somewhere on here an answer from @DavidCarlisle which gets the information I want but I can't find that answer again. It used `\expandafter\meaning\the\font` and it does print what I need plus stuff I don't.

How can I "save" that information and extract the substring which is just the human friendly font name? So it would capture `NotoSerif-ExtraBold` from example c below.

I thought the source code for `fontspec` might show me but I can't understand it.

I have seen `\StrBetween` from `xstring` but I can't make it work.

```latex
StrBetween ( \StrBetween{\expandafter\meaning\the\font}{s}{t} )
```

has nothing between the ears ( )
I think it should at least print `elec` since the output starts `select font`. I thought may `StrBetween` was seeing the actual `\expandafter...` so I tried `\expandafter\expandafter...` but that did not work either.

#### Minimal Not Working Example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xstring}

% I don't know if you are supposed to load the packages
\usepackage{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{noto}

% The font choices are deliberately silly to show the font name printing is working
\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Medium}[
     BoldFont       = NotoSerif-ExtraBold
    ,ItalicFont     = NotoSerif-ExtraLightItalic
    ,BoldItalicFont = NotoSerif-BlackItalic
]
\setsansfont{NotoSans-CondensedMedium}[
     BoldFont       = NotoSans-ExtraCondensedBlack
    ,ItalicFont     = NotoSans-LightItalic
    ,BoldItalicFont = NotoSans-CondensedSemiBoldItalic
]
\setmonofont{NotoSansMono-Regular}[
     BoldFont       = NotoSansMono-ExtraCondensedExtraBold
    ,ItalicFont     = AnonymousPro-Italic
    ,BoldItalicFont = AnonymousPro-BoldItalic.ttf
    % could not get it to work without the .ttf
]

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\howbig}{\f@size}
\newcommand*{\whatfontami}{\f@family}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
a. \normalfont serif normal \rmdefault\ \howbig\ pt

b. \normalfont serif normal \expandafter\meaning\the\font\ \howbig\ pt

c. \normalfont serif bold \bfseries\expandafter\meaning\the\font\ \howbig\ pt

d. \normalfont sans italic \sffamily\expandafter\meaning\the\font\ \howbig\ pt

e. \normalfont mono bold italic \ttfamily\bfseries\itshape\expandafter\meaning\the\font\ \howbig\ pt
\end{document}
```

[image: correct but unusable output]

which used `\expandafter\meaning\the\font` to print some font information, for example:

. The font name I w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want? Sorry for not mixing the mono fonts, but there are problems with AnonymousPro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% The font choices are deliberately silly to show the font name printing is working
\setmainfont{NotoSerif}[
  UprightFont    = *-Medium,
  BoldFont       = *-ExtraBold,
  ItalicFont     = *-ExtraLightItalic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BlackItalic,
  Scale = 0.9
]
\setsansfont{NotoSans}[
  UprightFont    = *-CondensedMedium,
  BoldFont       = *-ExtraCondensedBlack,
  ItalicFont     = *-LightItalic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-CondensedSemiBoldItalic,
  Scale = MatchUppercase,
]
\setmonofont{AnonymousPro}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Scale = MatchUppercase,
]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\extractfont}{}
 {
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \fontname\font }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \:.* } { } \l_tmpa_str
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A \[(.*)\] \Z } { \1 } \l_tmpa_str
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \.[^\.]* \Z } { } \l_tmpa_str
  \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\howbig}{\f@size}
\newcommand*{\whatfontami}{\f@family}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

a. {serif normal \rmdefault\ \howbig\ pt}

b. {serif normal \extractfont\ \howbig\ pt}

c. {serif bold \bfseries\extractfont\ \howbig\ pt}

d. {sans italic \sffamily\extractfont\ \howbig\ pt}

e. {mono bold italic \ttfamily\bfseries\itshape\extractfont\ \howbig\ pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The primitive construct `\fontname\font` provides the current font name (without `select font` at the beginning) and I remove everything from the first colon inclusive, then possible brackets `[]` around the font name and finally a possible extension (from a period followed by characters not including periods up to the end).

Comment: Perfect, thank you @egreg. Your code that strips the unwanted parts is even better than I had hoped for. The exact mono font didn't matter. I was just picking fonts with different names to test the code really was picking the current font.